# java.lang.NumberFormatException in ImageIO during class initialization

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Can anyone help me with this error:

I am just trying to open an image file. The file exists and the file path is correct.

```
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(path, "img.jpg"));    
    ....

} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Error :

```
Caught and handled this exception :
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.jaiimageio.impl.common.ImageUtil.processOnRegistration(ImageUtil.java:1401)
    at com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.wbmp.WBMPImageReaderSpi.onRegistration(WBMPImageReaderSpi.java:96)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.SubRegistry.registerServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.registerServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at abhi.Abhi.main(Abhi.java:496)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code at this line? `abhi.Abhi.main(Abhi.java:496)`?

Comment: BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(path, "img.jpg"));

Comment: Do you provide any custom `ImageIO` plugins?

Comment: This appears to be a known bug: https://github.com/medusa-project/cantaloupe/issues/176

Comment: No i didnot use any custom plugins.But because of this pdfbox's PDImageXObject.createFromFileByExtension() is also giving same error

Comment: Also this https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154860

Comment: Note that in the OpenJDK but database this is marked as RESOLVED.  Please verify that you have the latest version of the JDK.

Comment: ***HINT*** when tracking down errors, it is ALWAYS advisable to enter the exception name in Google and the class name that is involved, to see if the two correlate in existing bug descriptions.

Comment: I am just curious. What is you Java version?

Comment: My java version is 9.0.4 .

Comment: @JimGarrison It's resolved in the JDK, as it's not a JDK bug... The problem must be fixed in the third party code that parses the version information (and doesn't handle the new versioning format of Java 9). It [seems to be fixed in this case](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core/blob/0feba94520cc9cb59c58167f3b13dd712f100bbc/src/main/java/com/github/jaiimageio/impl/common/ImageUtil.java#L1422) though, OP just need to update his JAI dependencies.

Comment: I Updated my JDK and now everything works fine.